# How to use INSERT INTO RETURNING value as a subquery?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use the return value of a subquery in another query, but there is an error when using `INSERT INTO` as a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM (INSERT INTO items (name) VALUES ("test") RETURNING id);
```

The error message says:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

you could use a CTE for that

But don't use in Postgres doubole quotes for text, it thinks that is a column, use single quotes instead

```
CREATE TABLe items(id SERIAL, name varchar(29))
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
WITH INSERT_CTE as (INSERT INTO items (name) VALUES ('test') RETURNING id)
SELECT id FROM INSERT_CTE;
```

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YdNHy94v)